# React js Node js ExpressJS Cross-site session/cookie management issue

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies, express-session

Hi i am trying to implement authentication using express-session problem is that my frontend is on another domain and my backend is on another domain.
Suppose frontend is on domain domainA.com while backend is on domain domainB.com
Now when i try on my local computer with localhost session is successfully created and cookie is saved but when i deployed it and try to create session on domainA.com using domainB.com then cookie is not set due to which session is not working at all.
I tried app.set(proxy,1) etc and everything on the internet. I have been trying to solve this problem from months and i tried every solution online but it doesn't store cookie on domainA.com from domainB.com.
Also when i map anydomain.com on localhost then try to login and save cookie from localhost:4000 to anydomain.com (that is mapped to localhost:3000) then cookie is not saved it means cookie is not saved on cross-site.

```
 //Server.js file
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

const serverInfo = require('./Info/ServerInfo');
const session = require('./Session/Session');
const cors = require('./Cors/Cors');
const routes = require('./Routes/Routes');

const app = express();

const Server = async () => {


    app.use(express.json());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(session);
    app.use(cors);
    app.use(routes);

    app.listen(serverInfo.port, () => {

        console.log(`Server Is Running At Port ${serverInfo.port}`);

    });

}

module.exports.start = Server;
```

//Session.js

```
const session = require('express-session');
const uuid = require('uuid');

const serverInfo = require('../Info/ServerInfo');

module.exports = session({

    secret: serverInfo.sessionKey,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
        sameSite: 'none',
        httpOnly: true,
        secure: false
    },
    genid: (req) => uuid.v4()

});
```

Comment: Enable cors with the origin of your frontend so in your backend when you specify to use cors as middleware do `app.use(cors({ origin: 'https://domainA.com' }))`. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuring-cors

Comment: Alreay Allowed.
const cors = require('cors');

const whitelist = [

    'http://localhost:3000',
    

];

const corsOptions = {

    origin: (origin, callback) => {

        //if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin)
        if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1)
            callback(null, true);
        else
            callback('UnAuthorized!');

    },
    methods: ['POST', 'GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true

}

module.exports = cors(corsOptions);

Comment: I'm assuming since your using react you are using either fetch or axios. Did add `credentials: 'include'` to your request?

Comment: `import axios from 'axios';
import FileDownload from 'js-file-download';

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/api";
const headers = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
const options = { headers: headers, withCredentials: true };
const fileOptions = { responseType: "blob" };`